# Componente "Link to" do react não funciona

Tags: react

Estou aprendendo sobre React Router, mas o componente "link to" do react-router-dom não funciona. Como faço para funcionar?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from "./componentes/layout/Navbar";
import Footer from "./componentes/layout/Footer";
import Home from './componentes/pages/Home';
import Empresa from './componentes/pages/Empresa';
import Contato from './componentes/pages/Contato';

function App() {

  return (
      <div className='App'>
          <Router>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/empresa" element={<Empresa />} />
              <Route path="/contato" element={<Contato />} />
            </Routes>
          </Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Footer />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Navbar() {

    return (
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/empresa">Empresa</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/contato">Contato</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Salve, meu caro! "Não está funcionando" dificulta MUITO a resposta. O ideal seria você explicar o que quer dizer com "não está funcionando" -- inclusive apontando o código e links que são exibidos na página.

Comment: Salve, César. Não estar funcionando significa que o texto na página web aparece como um texto normal ao invés de um link que direciona para outra página. Abraços

Comment: Por que você importou BrowseRouter as Link? Acho que são dois componentes diferentes, não? O que acontece se você tirar ```import { BrowserRouter as Link } from 'react-router-dom';``` e deixar no lugar ```import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';```?

Comment: Se você importou BroserRouter as Link, ao escrever ```Link``` você está chamando o componente ```BrowserRouter```, de uma forma que não tem nada a ver com o objetivo dele. Se eu entendi direito, você quer usar o componente ```Link``` mesmo, e não usar Link como apelido para outro componente.